# PhantomJSDriver- How to initialize the driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Can someone tell me how I begin to test with PhantomJS? I have downloaded the PhantomJS exe file and also set my "path" variable.

And I do something similar for chrome like

`if(config.getProperty("browser").equals("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver= new ChromeDriver();
        }`

which is

```
if(config.getProperty("browser").equals("phantom"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new PhantomJSDriver();
    }
```

But, this does not work. Please help. I do not want to use RemoteWebDriver or GhostDriver

Comment: "Doesn't work" means *what*? What errors & stack traces are you getting?

Comment: It does not run my test case... No errors! but I dont see any output like for example the system.out.println statements in my testcase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
if(config.getProperty("browser").equals("phantom"))
{
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "C:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver= new PhantomJSDriver();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJSDriver accepts path to executable as a constructor argument:

```
if (config.getProperty("browser").equals("phantom"))
    driver= new PhantomJSDriver("C:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: in above line driver= new PhantomJSDriver("C:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");        do we need to use phantom.exe or chromedriver.exe.         please confirm

Answer (score 0):

Find the phantomjs code below and set the property key and value:

```
//System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path","phantomjs.exe path");


System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ExternalLibraryFiles/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");

driver =new PhantomJSDriver();
```